# why should we have small number of registers?

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor, register

I read in my book that we should have a small number of registers (such as 32 registers)

What are some reasons?

Comment: Registers for what?

Comment: Because they're expensive.

Comment: Your book is wrong or outdated. Many CPUs and uCs have much more registers than that.

Comment: If you look before 1980, many CPUs had 100s of registers.  The 68xx and 808x series were unique that they had so few.  Your question, is too vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few obvious ones:

1. They take up space in your instruction encoding. If you had 256 registers, for instance, you'd need to use 8 bits in an instruction just to specify a single register. This could increase the overall size of instructions, or limit the types of instructions that can be encoded; having fewer registers, generally speaking, makes your instruction encoding denser.
2. From a practical standpoint, there's a limit to how many registers are useful for applications, and 32 is at the upper end of that; few applications end up ever using all of the registers! 16 (as seen on ARM, among others) is generally sufficient, and some architectures get away with even fewer (like 32-bit x86, which has only 8).
3. They take up physical space on the CPU. There might be better things you could use that for, like more cache, or more execution units.

That all being said, modern CPUs often have tons of registers. For instance, an Intel Haswell CPU has 168 integer registers! What's different, though, is that these registers aren't exposed directly in the instruction set; instead, they're used for register renaming to support out-of-order and speculative execution.

Comment: To expand on OoO, superscalar designs and speculation: The back end of modern high-end processors are basically so sophisticated that the registers are only used as temporary names in a sort of abstract way to encode the data dependencies of the algorithm. It's probably rare to have more than 32 independent values that need to stay reachable in registers for good performance. Thus, adding another bit to the register number adds fairly little extra performance but brings a potentially significant penalty in instruction density.

Answer (score 2):

There are different views on this, and they come and go like fashions as the technological sweet spots shift.

From the point of view of instruction set design, one view (I was introduced to in the 1970s) is that you should have 0, 1 or infinite registers.

0 and infinity are essentially the same case - both are flat storage models.
1 register is called the accumulator, and as it is the default target for most instructions, it consumes no space in the instructions to address.

A "small" number of registers historically, was 4 or 8 registers, with 32 being a pretty close approximation to infinity when gates or registers were expensive.

The problem with such a large number of registers is addressing them : to address 32 registers takes 5 bits, and if they are to be general purpose, many instructions need to address 2 sources and a destination - that's 15 bits wasted in a single instruction. (Instructions are classified in terms of the number of addresses they need - this is a three address instruction).

So it's obvious that 32 GP registers had to wait until 32-bit instructions were affordable - and that even then, almost half your executable size can be wasted simply addressing registers.

---

What you really want is not a small number of registers, but a small amount of wasted space addressing them.

The alternative "accumulator" approach saves 5 bits by always writing to the same register' or 10 bits if the accumulator is also one of the sources - but costs a few more "move" instructions to/from the accumulator. That is, the accumulator allows much smaller "one address" instructions.

Clever compilation techniques can then be used to reorder computations to minimise the number of wasted "move"s, and superscalar techniques could use several physical accumulators shadowing the single architected one, eliminating further "moves" or re-scheduling them in parallel with other operations.

Another approach allowing "infinite registers" without wasting address space is the [stack machine](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack_computers/), where instead of the accumulator, the default target is "TOS" or "Top-Of-Stack", which is effectively a base address into a large register bank, and small offsets from it are encoded into fewer than 5 bits for other operands.

Historical note : one approach towards this was the "sliding register windows" of the SPARC architecture addressing a local subset of a larger number of registers.

The ARM swaps in additional registers during interrupt handlers for similar reasons. It also has its "Thumb" instruction sets to increase code density but I have not studied these.

These logical architectures and others fell by the wayside in the 1980s as the apparent simplicity of straight RISC allowed it to hit the market faster with new processes, and more easily adopt techniques like pipelining, superscalar, and reordering.

The latter techniques proved equally applicable to CISC architectures, notably the x86 which survived on its huge base of legacy code. 
They are probably also useful for accumulator and stack architectures, but have not been extensively applied to them.